# Running commands after Composer package installed globally

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created a Composer package which is designed to be installed globally, it's basically a package to spin up Docker environments for projects that I use a lot for local development. I'd like to share my package but would like to make it more user friendly.

Currently when the package is installed (with `composer global require me/my-package-name`), the user needs to take some extra steps:

- `cd` into the install location and run `composer install` (inside the root of my package in their vendor dir)
- On MacOS, users also need to run `cd docker && chmod +x phpenv`
- Add above `docker` folder to their PATH

I'm trying to make this less of a pain, so I attempted to add a post package install command - `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-package-install": [
        "DannyXCII\\Environment\\Install\\Installer::postPackageInstall"
    ]
},
```

```
public static function postPackageInstall(): void
{
    $path = dirname(__DIR__, 3);
    exec("cd $path && composer install && composer update && composer dump-autoload && cd docker && chmod +x phpenv");
}
```

After trying and failing to get this to work when installing this globally I realise now that this script [won't get called when this package is installed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-), only when packages are required and `composer install` is ran inside this package, as:

> Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts.

So, I believe in this case, the solution would be to add this script to the *root project* - so I'd need to update this script and add to the `composer.json` file in `C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Roaming\Composer`(?), as would anyone else wanting to use this - so this doesn't solve my issues regarding usability.

I have been searching and attempting to resolve this for a while but found this quite a difficult topic to search on.

**Essentially, my question is:** how can I run commands such as `composer install` inside my package after it is globally required without the user having to do so manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've now solved this - so, you know how you can run `composer global require laravel/installer` and immediately type `laravel` and you'll see some help text from the command? This is the same level of convenience I wanted to achieve with my package so I decided where better to look to see how it's done?

I was thinking about this incorrectly; I don't want a `vendor` directory inside my globally installed package and I shouldn't ever expect commands like `composer install` inside my package.

I was able to remove the two blocks from above. Inside my `phpenv` script, where I'm looking for the autoloader from within my package, I also added an additional check, so that this will use the autoloader at `C:/Users/Danny/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/autoload.php` if it exists - **this removes the need to run `composer install`** (one step down):

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__, 3) . '/autoload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__, 3) . '/autoload.php';
} else {
    require dirname(__DIR__, 1) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

Assuming you have your Composer `bin` directory added to your path (something like `C:/Users/Danny/AppData/Roaming/Composer/bin`), I was able to remove the need to add the path to this package specifically by making sure that the script to execute my commands was mapped to the above `bin` directory. I moved my `phpenv` script to a `bin` directory in my package and then added the following to my `composer.json` - **this removes the need to add the path to the script directory to my environment variables path**:

```
"bin": [
    "bin/phpenv"
],
```